# error: no matching function for call to 'Subclass::...'

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism

I'm doing an OOP project for school, and I'm currently stuck because of the following problem :

Let's say that `A` is my base class, that `B` inherits from `A` and `C` inherits from `B`.

`A` has a method to check whether two A-type objects are colliding.

This method is not redefined/overdriven in `C`, but I have to use it in this subclass.

```cpp
class A 
{
  public:
    bool isColliding(A);
};

class B : public A 
{
};

class C : public B 
{
  public:
    void Eat(B);
}

void C::Eat(B objectB) 
{
  if(isColliding(objectB)) 
  {
  }
}
```

This is an oversimplification of the code, I was just trying to convey the idea.

It returns the following :

```
error : no matching function for call to 'C::isColliding(B)'
note: candidate: bool A::isColliding(A)
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'B' to 'A'.
```

How do I get this method to interpret C and B as being A for it to work ?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Currently, your code doesn't compile because `A::isColliding()` is **_private_** method of `A`. After changing it to `public`, it compiles just fine: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MXCCLmmb6dprMUFX

Comment: Does the rest of the error message perhaps contain the words "is private in this context"?

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to specify it in my post, but in my code I made these methods public. I've updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access a base-class member, you have to say so explicitly, like this:

```
if(A::isColliding(objectB)) {
```

Comment: I tried to write ```if(A::isColliding(objectB)) {``` but it still says 

error : no matching function for call to 'C::isColliding(B)'

note: candidate: bool A::isColliding(A)

note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'B' to 'A'.

Comment: That's because `A::isColliding` takes an object of type `A` as it's parameter and you're passing in an object of type `B`. Perhaps you want it to take a *reference* to an object of type `A` and pass in a *reference* to an object of type `B`? That would work because of inheritance.

Comment: The real code is a bit more complicated than what I wrote. Actually, I have a list of pointers on B objects, and I then use a for (auto&) loop to iterate on each of the pointer, and the goal is to check whether the pointed object B is colliding with object C.

Comment: Then read *pointer* for *reference* in my last comment. That work too because of inheritance.